# Proof of WOP by using the infimum property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

**WOP**: Every non-empty subset of natural numbers has a least element.

The proof of WOP is as follows, it uses the infimum property:

> Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Then $A$ is bounded below (by $1$), so it has an infimum $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, choose $n_0\in A$ such that $n_0-a\leq 1/4$. It follows that $n_0-1<a\leq n_0$. Since there are no elements from $A$ in $(n_0-1,n_0)$ or in $(-\infty,a)$ (since $a$ is a lower bound), there are no elements from $A$ in $(-\infty,a)\cup (n_0-1,n_0)=(-\infty,n_0)$. That is, all elements of $A$ are greater than or equal to $n_0$, which is a least element of $A$.

What I don't understand is the part:

> Since there are no elements from $A$ in $(n_0-1,n_0)$ or in $(-\infty,a)$ (since $a$ is a lower bound) ...

How to see that $(n_0-1,n_0)\cap A=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 1):

That follows from $A$ being a set of integers, the second part follows from the fact that $a\leq m$ for all $m\in A$, since $a$ is supposed to be $\text{inf}(A)$.

Comment: How exactly would you prove that there is no integer between two consecutive integers without using WOP?

Comment: Suppose there is an integer between them, then substract it from either end of your interval, the size of the resulting number is strictly smaller than 1, can that happen for an integer?

Answer (score 0):

If $n_0$ is a natural number, then the open intervals $(n_0,n_0+1)$ and $(n_0-1,n_0)$ are intervals which contain no natural numbers, they have elements of the form $n_0+\epsilon$ or $n_0-\epsilon$ where $0<\epsilon<1.$

Comment: How do you prove that $(n_0-1,n_0)$ contains no natural numbers without using WOP (that is not proven yet)?